# How to evaluate a line integral over the lemniscate of Bernoulli

Tags: curves

Evaluate the integral over the $\int_c$ |y| ds where curve c is given by the equation $(x^2+y^2)^2=40^2(x^2-y^2)$

I used polar coordinates but keep getting 0 as a answer. Help?

Comment: Welcome to math.se! Can you give a little more detail about your computation that gives $0$?